# How to get the audio output volume of a video tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video, dom-events

I don't want to get the volume set by the user for the video, I want to get the total volume of the audio of a video. Can someone please tell me how to do this?. I want to do this because I want to highlight the video which has the highest audio output with a colored border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to get the audio level of each video, similar to a VU meter for audio tracks or an indication in a video conference of who who is speaking loudest.

If so then an AnalyserNode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) is most likely that you want:

> [An AnalyserNode] is an AudioNode that passes the audio stream unchanged from the input to the output, but allows you to take the generated data, process it, and create audio visualizations.

There is a good overview of how to use it here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API

And a working demo, with the excellent name 'Voice-change-o-matic' - this uses the microphone as the audio source but you can modify this as needed:

- https://mdn.github.io/voice-change-o-matic/